# Loading and setting saved value for a Menu in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, menu

I have a simple popup menu in flex, a mx Menu, and I use the Menu.initMenu to create the menu relying on an XML List defined as the data provider.

The menu has check box items, and every time I call a load(values:Array) function in the class which contains the menu's instance, I want to check the relevant items.

How do I dynamically load values and change the menu's selections ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it :

1. set the menu, and give EVERY menuitem a label attribute :

   ```
   private var subMenuDataMain:XMLList = new XMLList(
       "<menuitem label='Title' icon='' enabled='false'/>" +
       "<menuitem label='' type='separator'/>" +
       "<menuitem label='SHOW_DEMO' type='check' eventName='SHOW_DEMO' />" +
       "<menuitem label='' type='separator'/>");
   ```
2. create an auxiliary function to turn on menuitems for a given Label (if it's a 2-level menu item, provide also the subMenuID which is the second item's label name):

   ```
       function toggleMenuItem(menuID:String, subMenuID:String, toggle:Boolean):void
       {
           if (subMenuID != "")
               subMenuDataSets.(@label == menuID).menuitem.(@label == subMenuID).@toggled = toggle;
           else
               subMenuDataSets.(@label == menuID).@toggled = toggle;
       }
   ```
3. implement a function that initializes the menu's values :

   ```
   public function setMenuOptions(obj:SampleObject):void {
       toggleMenuItem("SHOW_DEMO", "", (obj.demoISShown());
    }
   ```